# Search and replace a substring javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a `String` something like `var someString = 'Some foo email string {{Email18}} bla bla'`.

I need to search and replace a substring `{{Email18}}` but I don't know the digit or number part. I want to something like `someString.replace("{{Email*}}", "Foo")` and resultant string be like `'Some foo email string Foo bla bla'`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `\d` character class if at least one digit is present at the end of substring:

```
var someString = 'Some foo email string {{Email18}} bla bla',
    replaced = someString.replace(/{{Email\d{1,}}}/, "Foo");

console.log(replaced);  // "Some foo email string Foo bla bla"
```

Comment: Can you also please tell me how I can get the substring like `someString.search(/{{Email\d{1,}}}/)` which will give me `{{Email18}}`?

Comment: @NitinAggarwal, use `match` method: `var subStr = someString.match(/{{Email\d{1,}}}/); console.log(subStr[0]);  // will give "{{Email18}}" `

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression match to replace:

```
someString.replace(/\{\{Email\d+\}\}/, "Foo")
```

where you escape the brackets (operators) and have an expression for 1 or more digits (`\d+`).

Comment: Are you sure the regex is right? It is not working in my code.